# Finding counter examples for two statements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Are the following  False? I do think they should be false but couldn't find any counter examples to justify them

Let $(X,\preceq_x)$ $(Y\prec_y)$ be partially ordered sets and let $f:X\to Y$ be an order preserving function and $A\subseteq X$

$m$ is a maximal element of A $\Rightarrow$ $f(m)$ is a maximal element of $f(A)$

$l$ =$SupA$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(l) =sup(f(A))$

Comment: Why do you think they are false?

Comment: In your last one, I think you want $f(l)=\sup(f(A))$  You can also put a backslash before sup to get it in operator typeface.

Comment: Well I thought that in the 1st one there could be a $x$ which is not comparable with $m$ but $f(m)\preceq_y f(x)$ hence $f(m)$ is not a minimal

Comment: Excellent! This is your counterexample. Let $A=\{x,m\}$ where the elements are incomparable. Then construct $Y$ such that $f(m) \prec_y f(x)$ and you are done. What are you thoughts on the second part?

Comment: Thanks! As for the second part I thought that $f(l)$ would be an upperbound for $f(A)$ just thought that it may not be the least upper bound or Sup may not exist, may be wrong though

Answer (score 1):

One way to get a counterexample for the second one is to introduce a gap between $f[A]$ and $f(\sup A)$. Take $X=Y=[0,1]$ with the usual order on each, let $A=[0,1)$, and let

$$f:X\to Y:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
x/2,&\text{if }x\in A\\
1,&\text{if }x=1\;.
\end{cases}$$

Then $f[A]=\left[0,\frac12\right)$, so $\sup f[A]=\frac12$, but $f(\sup A)=f(1)=1$.